# I'm dual booting win7 and ubuntu12.10 and ubuntu thinks there's no space on the hard drive

Tags: 12.10, windows, hard-drive

I'm dual booting win7 home premium and ubuntu 12.10 32bit (the machine is 64bit, Intel Celeron), and if I check the C:\ drive with win7, it shows about 90 gb remaining.  I'm new to ubuntu, and recently ubuntu said that only about 800 mb was left on the hard drive.  How do I expand the amount of space ubuntu takes up on the hard drive so that it doesn't run out of space?
This is a wubi install.

-Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a Wubi install? Please edit your question with the results of `df -h`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did Install it with Wubi, didn't you?

In my personal experience Installing Ubuntu inside Windows doesn't work at all...

Now, if you want you can install it **alongslide Windows**... Just follow the instructions of the answer of this question:

[Can i install/run Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop (ACER 5755G)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260064/can-i-install-run-ubuntu-12-10-on-my-laptop-acer-5755g/260081#260081)

Now, your problem is that when you installed Ubuntu with Wubi, you probably got the option to say how much space did you want for Ubuntu, now, 30 gbs is good for it if you're new... (you probably will not need a lot)... If you're running out of space, you can always use an external HDD, or partition your HDD so Ubuntu can use it... (give it a ext4 or ext3 format)